# Dell T110. System board failure after RAM upgrade

Tags: memory, motherboard, dell-poweredge

I upgrade T110 RAM from 4G to 16G.
4G RAM is default RAM(2G + 2G).
New RAM is SAMSUNG 4G PC3-10600R-09-10-E1-P0(Manual sheets says DDR3, 13333MHz).
When switch on, the diagnostic lights indicate no.1 & no.4. According to manual, this means "system board failure".

What is the "system board failure"?
How can I fix this? Do I need jumper setting or somthing?

Comment: No; It sounds like the T110 does not support 16GB. Specific information is required;  For instance the specific CPU.

Comment: Install the old ram, does it work now?

Comment: old RAM is working. CPU is Xeon & spec sheet says "Up to 16GB (4 DIMM slots): 1GB/2GB/4GB DDR3 up to 1333MHz".

Comment: If the diagnostic lights indicate RAM error, I replace my new RAM. But I can't understand why the error is "system board failure".